# Can you generate math problems that are solveable?

Tags: problem-solving, linear-programming, random, integer-programming

If you take Linear Programming, it problems are formulated like this:

> You know that Cabinet X costs 10 cents per unit, requires 6 square feet
> of floor space, and holds 8 cubic feet of files.
> Cabinet Y costs 20 dollars per unit, requires 8 square feet of floor
> space, and holds 12 cubic feet of files.
>
> You have been given 140 dollar for this purchase, though you don't have
> to spend that much. The office has room for no more than 72 square feet
> of cabinets.
>
> How many of which model should you buy, in order to maximize storage volume?

But you notate it as a math formula, and not in words. Now suppose I replace all the values in this formula(10, 6, 8, 20, 12, 140, 72) with random other numbers, so I create a completely new problem.

- Do they take longer to solve, than to verify the solution?
- Can I check that they are solveable without solving them?
- Can I check how difficult they will be to solve, without solving them?

Comment: Start with a solution - number of X and Y cabinets.  Make sure there is enough money and space for them.  Then there is at least one solution.

Comment: @Michael So I pick random X and Y, until I find a X/Y pair that is solveable? And can I also make sure that each X/Y pair will be equally hard to solve?

Comment: Pick how many $X$ and $Y$, then their cost, area and capacity.  Finally calculate how much area and money you need to buy and install those cabinets, and allow the user that much or a bit more area and money.  I don't know whether they will be equally hard to solve, nor how to make sure of that.

Comment: While it is surely easy to solve your little problem, mathematics is not yet in a state for a definitive answer to your general questions.

Comment: This question is too vague, in my view. With a *real world solver*, of *course* the problems are going to take different amounts of time to solve when you substitute in different numeric values. Some will be infeasible, others will have a solution "farther" in some sense from the solver's natural starting point, etc. etc. Differences in a few iterations are commonplace. But in practice nobody cares, and nobody should. In *theory*, the problems are all NP-hard, but of course one could enumerate the search space, and for some values, that space will be larger.

Answer (score 1):

All problems of this structure are solvable.  You can find the maximum number of X cabinets by checking each constraint.  In your example, there is room for $12$ of them, so that is the maximum.  Similarly, there is a maximum of $9$ Y cabinets.  Now you can just loop over $x$ from $0$ to $12$ and $y$ from $0$ to $9$,check whether you can fit $x$ type X cabinets and $y$ type Y cabinets, if so compute the volume, and report the optimum result.

In your example it is clear that Y cabinets are more efficient than X cabinets and we are able to use all the floor space with Y cabinets.  Also the cost is so low that it is not a constraint.  This makes the problem easy.  You want conflicting desires to make it harder.  If you raised the prices dramatically, so you couldn't afford all the Y cabinets you want, it would be harder.

Comment: You can fit nine Y cabinets and afford seven Y cabinets or $1400$ X cabinets (possibly a typo).

Comment: This linear programming problem is a toy problem for industrial problems that may have untold trillions of possible solutions; so you look for optima in corners of the feasible region.  So, to write random ones, pick the corners, and calculate other parameters that lead to those corners.

Comment: @Michael Can you elaborate on how I would 'pick' those corners?

Comment: Keep in mind this is an integer problem. At this size it is still a no-brainer, but such problems are still NP-hard.

Comment: @RossMillikan I may have picked the wrong example to illustrate the question, but I mean it more for any structured linear programming, not specifically for this one. And that they are solveable does not necessary mean they are equally hard. Im especially interested in making sure they will all be hard.